# Without aggregation SQL Server pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

Table name `int_table`. Columns are `col_name, col_value`

```
col_name    col_value
----------------------
 A            aa
 B            bb
 C            cc
 D            dd
 D            ddd
 E            eee
```

I need output like this

```
A        B          C           D        E
---------------------------------------------
aa       bb         cc          dd       eee
                                ddd
```

It's sample values. My table has more than 30 rows like this.

This is my attempt:

```
select * 
from int_table 
pivot (max(col_value) 
       for col_name in (A, B, C, D, E)) as tt
```

with aggregation function it's showing an error.

How can I get this solution using `pivot`?

I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select A,B,C,D,E        
from (
   select col_name, col_value,
          row_number() over (partition by col_name order by col_value) as rn
   from int_table
) as src
pivot (max(col_value) for col_name in (A,B,C,D,E)) as pvt
```

The trick here is to use a calculated column produced by `ROW_NUMBER` window function, so as to differentiate between records having the same `col_name` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70f54/1)

Comment: +1, *Note for OP*: to get blank values instead of `NULLS` you could use `COALESCE` in following: `select COALESCE(A,'') AS A,
    COALESCE(B,'') AS B,
    COALESCE(C,'') AS C,
    COALESCE(D,'') AS D,
    COALESCE(E,'') AS E      
from (....`